# Is there a way to change only the value of JavaPairRDD in Spark?

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-spark

Say I have already a JavaPairRDD. The main purpose is just to modify the second value and don't change the pair key. How could I do this?
For example, I have a JavaPairRDD which has value:

```
("first", "1;2")
("second", "3;4")
```

So I want to change this into form:

```
("first", "3")
("second", "7")
```

I know we can first map and then reduce, but this is just one simple example, my situation could be much more complex if we map and then reduce. Are there any way we can directly modify the value of JavaPairRDD just like iterating an array?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, certainly. Use `mapValues()`:

```
JavaPairRDD<Long,Integer> pairRDD = ...
JavaPairRDD<Long,String> mapped = pairRDD.mapValues(
  new Function() {
    @Override
    public String call(Integer i) {
      return i.toString();
    }
  );
```

This turns each `Integer` value into its `String` representation for example. Key stays the same.

Comment: Technically you are not modifying the RDD (because its immutable), but creating a new RDD.  However, this is the correct way to do this. Since all of the transformations before an action are executed together, there is not necessarily any extra storage being used.

Comment: Yes, I don't think I suggested that pairRDD is mutated.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the example of mapValues:

**Input**

```
("first", "1;2")
("second", "3;4")
```

**Code:**

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> pairs = lines.mapToPair(f -> {
            String[] tokens = f.toString().split(",");
            return new Tuple2<String,String>(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
        });

        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> output = pairs.mapValues(f -> {
            String[] tokens = f.split(";");
            Integer a = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            Integer b = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            return a + b;
        });

        List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> res = output.collect();
        for(Tuple2 t : res){
            System.out.println(t._1 + "," + t._2);
        }
```